# <<not bound>> on ghidra function, can't create an association with the needed .dll

Tags: assembly, dll, reverse-engineering, ghidra

I'm trying to reverse engineer an .exe, but it's my first time using ghidra, I used more x64dbg, but it doesn't have all the features I need. When I search a function from the imports, the dll called by it, isn't associated and I have no idea why it doesn't automatically do that. Need some help with this, I haven't found this error anywhere.

[image: .Dll association missing]